# invalid syntax when running a function call expression using python 2.7.14

Tags: python, function, call

can not run the function call expression on idle python 2.7.14. what could be wrong with the code below?

```
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'apple',
         'orange', 'grape', 'kiwi']  # init the array
#reports the frequency of every item in a list

def analyze_list(l):
    counts = {}
    for item in l:

        if item in counts:
            counts[item] = counts[item] + 1
            else:
                counts[item] = 1

                return counts

    #let analyze a list
    counts =  analyze_list(fruit)
    print counts
```

Comment: You do know that indentation in Python is important, right? Your if-else is indented wrongfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't indented properly, the else or elif statement that corresponds to an if statement must be on the same indentation block.

```
fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'kiwi']  # init the array
#reports the frequency of every item in a list 
def analyze_list(l):
    counts = {}
    for item in l:

        if item in counts:
            counts[item] = counts[item] + 1
        else:
            counts[item] = 1

            return counts

    #let analyze a list
    counts =  analyze_list(fruit)
    print counts
```

Notice how the if statement is even with the else statement.